# how to export test cases from test lab in excel format [ which has test case full description ]in ALM version 12?

Tags: testing, export, testcase, alm

i want to export test cases from ALM 12 in their descriptive format as present in excelsheet before exporting. 
i am able to export from test plan, is there any way to export from test lab

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Business view Excel to export Test set data from Test Lab.

This will be the easiest way.